# Angular Material Automcomplete with object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

I want to create an autocomplete input with angular (17) and angular material. I have a an array ob objects (locations) which have an id, coordinates and optional an address. I already can filter the values and display them in the form input but I cannot manage it to only save only the address on the formcontrol. I can only store the whole object but I want to save only the id. Is this possible?

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Search"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [formControlName]="'location'" />
    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option">
        {{ displayFn(option) }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Component

```js
locations: Location[] = [
    { id: '1', coordinates: { lat: 10, lon: 20 }, address: { street: 'Street 1', housenumber: '1', city: 'City 1' } },
    { id: '2', coordinates: { lat: 30, lon: 40 }, address: { street: 'Another Street 2', housenumber: '2', city: 'City 2' } },
    { id: '3', coordinates: { lat: 50, lon: 60 } }
  ];
  form = this.createForm();
  filteredOptions: Observable<Location[]> = of([]);

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.form.controls['location'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.id)),
      map((id) => (id ? this._filter(id) : this.locations.slice()))
    );

  }

  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
      location: new FormControl<string>('')
    })
  }

  displayFn(location: Location): string {
    if(location) {
      if(location.address) {
        return location.address.street + ' ' + location.address.housenumber + ', ' + location.address.city
      } else {
        return location.coordinates.lat + ', ' + location.coordinates.lon;
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.locations.filter(
      (option) => {
        return option.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          (option.address &&
            (option.address.street.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
              option.address.city.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))) ||
          option.coordinates.lat.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          option.coordinates.lon.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: From my thinking, I think you need to separate it to have 2 (input) controls. The first input element is the `<mat-autocomplete>` that is used for filtering [without `[formControlName]="'location'"`]. The second (input) control is the hidden control that is used to store the selected location id. So, when the mat-autocomplete (option) is selected, you need to patch the `id` to the second control.  Also if possible, can you try to reproduce in StackBlitz? Thanks.

Comment: This is a good proposal. I try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code after the hint from Yong Shun to have a separate form control for the autocompletion. Now it works.

Template

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Search"
      [formControl]="location"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
    <mat-autocomplete
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option">
        {{ displayFn(option) }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Component

```js
locations: Location[] = [
    { id: '1', coordinates: { lat: 10, lon: 20 }, address: { street: 'Street 1', housenumber: '1', city: 'City 1' } },
    { id: '2', coordinates: { lat: 30, lon: 40 }, address: { street: 'Another Street 2', housenumber: '2', city: 'City 2' } },
    { id: '3', coordinates: { lat: 50, lon: 60 } }
  ];
  form = this.createForm();
  location = new FormControl<Location | null>(null);
  filteredOptions: Observable<Location[]> = of([]);

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.location.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => {
        if(value) {
         return typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.id
        }
        return null
      }),
      map((id) => {
        if (id) {
          this.form.controls['locationId'].setValue(id);
          return this._filter(id)
        }
        return this.locations.slice()
      })
    );

  }

  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
      locationId: new FormControl<string>('', { nonNullable: true})
    })
  }

  displayFn(location: Location): string {
    if(location) {
      if(location.address) {
        return location.address.street + ' ' + location.address.housenumber + ', ' + location.address.city
      } else {
        return location.coordinates.lat + ', ' + location.coordinates.lon;
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.locations.filter(
      (option) => {
        return option.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          (option.address &&
            (option.address.street.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
              option.address.city.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))) ||
          option.coordinates.lat.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          option.coordinates.lon.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Nice one, I think this `this.form.controls['locationId'].setValue(id);` line can move to the first `map`, when checking that the `value` is not a string type. Based on your current logic, every time the inputted text will set the locationId control. You can print out the whole locationId control's value/form in HTML, key-in the field, and observe the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[value]="option.id"`.
In this way when an option is selected, only the id of the Location object will be stored in the form control.

Comment: This is what I tested first. But then the autocompletion window cannot be closed and I can select multiple elements.